# Загрузка файлов на сайт через webview - Java, Android

Tags: android, webview

Возможно ли загружать файлы на сайт через Webview? Например мне надо загрузить картинку на сайт, который уменьшит мне изображение фотографии. Если это делать через Chrome, то вылезет окошко с выбором откуда можно взять файл. У меня это обычно встроенное приложение Файлы или же Загрузки. Как можно это реализовать в webview на Android?[image: При нажатии на кнопку "Выберете файл" в Google Chrome]

Comment: Как-то давно я не возился с `WebView` и подзабыл уже что к чему. Но вроде выбор файлов работал "из коробки". У вас разрешение на доступ к ФС объявлено-получено? Может надо просетить `WebChromClient` и/или настройки какие включить. На крайняк в `WebChromClient` есть метод [`onShowFileChooser`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri%5B%5D%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams)), который вы можете переопределить и реализовать выбор файла собственноручно.

Comment: @woesss все разрешения в манифесте есть. Скорее всего не настроен WebChromeClient. Точнее он у меня есть и отвечает за progressbar. Я не знаю просто какой код написать для того чтобы это было как в Chrome и других подобных браузерах

Comment: Насчёт "из коробки" похоже соврал - попробуйте разобраться с реализацией из ответа на en-SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46631047

Comment: @woesss ok. Спасибо